# Unity 2D angular velocity center

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I try to add angular velocity to my `GameObject` with this command:

```
rigidbody2D.angularVelocity = Random.value * tumble;
```

All works, but I want center of velocity be in the center of my rigidbody, but center is outside my `GameObject` and looks like every time in different place. How can I set rotation center to the center of my rigidbody?

Thanks!

Comment: Better ask your question here [Unity Answers](http://answers.unity3d.com/)

Comment: @TzahMama is this site is a part of StackExchange community, or not? Because it's very similar.

Comment: @DmytroZarezenko I don't think it is, it just happens to look a lot like it. Even some of the badges are the same.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to adjust your [Rigidbody2D's centerOfMass](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D-centerOfMass.html).

I find it easiest to create a child GameObject, position it where you want the center of mass to be, and set `rigidbody2D.centerOfMass` to the child object's `transform.localPosition`.

```cs
 rigidbody2D.centerOfMass = someChildObject.transform.position;
```

Comment: And how can I get that child object in the better way?

Comment: And I don't see `centerOfMass` property of the `rigidbody2D`, only for `rigidbody` :(

Comment: I have Unity 4.3.4 and have received error: `Assets/Scripts/Asteroid.cs(23,21): error CS1061: Type `UnityEngine.Rigidbody2D' does not contain a definition for `centerOfMass' and no extension method `centerOfMass' of type `UnityEngine.Rigidbody2D' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
`

Comment: Ah, `centerOfMass` was added in Unity 4.5.

Comment: I have installed new version and now I have created child object `centerOfMass` and added code `rigidbody2D.centerOfMass = transform.FindChild("centerOfMass").transform.localPosition` before code `rigidbody2D.angularVelocity = Random.value * tumble` but nothing. What wrong?